# CSS "left" property working properly in chrome but why not in others ( specifically Firefox, IE9, Safari, Opera)

Tags: css

```
ul.menu .about{
left: -602px;
}
```

This code is working in chrome very fine but in others browsers i am not getting same result. why this happening. Is there any pixel difference among  browsers. Any solution please?

Comment: what is the `position` value of `ul.menu .about`?

Comment: I kept position value 'absolute'

Comment: then it should work. Can you please provide a POC on jsfiddle?

Comment: When results differ between browsers, the first thing to do is check if you don't have errors. Different browsers handle errors differently! So validate your HTML and your CSS first.

Comment: Thank you all.
Actually there were  no errors in my code. Problem was in my browser. I tested my HTML document for different browser from www.browserstack.com and got excellent result. :)

Comment: @user3256184 Interesting. Which browser was the culprit?

Comment: :) 

The main culprit browser was IE !!!